# Unrecognized Selector Instance Error for Objective-C Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

I am just making a simple public method in a custom class, but whenever I create the class and call the method in a ViewController, I get this exception thrown.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[PTask testMethod]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003316300
```

I have read that it's some sort of memory issue, but I do not necessarily know how to fix it. Weirdly, there are other getters/setter methods in this class, but they are not affected by this problem.

I am have tried doing a @dynamic instead, but it keeps throwing the same error.

Here is the class I am having issues with:

Task.h

```
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Task : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *title;
//Deadline
//@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *desc;
@property (nonatomic) double priority;
@property (nonatomic) double percentage;

- (void) testMethod;
@end
```

Task.m

```
#import "Task.h"

@implementation Task {
    NSDate *deadline;
}

@dynamic title;
@dynamic priority;
@dynamic percentage;

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        deadline = [NSDate date];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)testMethod {
    NSLog(@"HELLO!");
}
@end
```

Comment: tested your code found no issue, can u eloberate on how you are getting that crash? Creating simply a instance and calling its method is not crashing

Comment: I create a new Task instance every time I unwind away from a addTask view controller. If I initialize an object there, I can call setTitle: setPriority fine but calling testMethod results in the error.

Comment: The error message says `PTask`.  Your source shows `Task`.  Something didn't translate to StackOverflow fully.   Also, mixing `@property` with instance variable declarations is generally a sign that things are off the rails.

Comment: I forgot to mention, PTask is like the NSManagedObject Entity version of Task. Aren't they the same thing?

Comment: "PTask is like the NSManagedObject Entity version of Task" That depends on how you defined that. Could you show that code?

Comment: `Task* toAdd = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PTask" inManagedObjectContext:context];`

Where PTask is a managed entity that has desc, priority, and title attribute.

Comment: In the case of the error message, `PTask` is a class – and nothing else. Please add the code, for creating an instance and sending the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so apparently I did an oopsie and what happened was that I defined never defined deadline in the NSManagedObject Entity xcodedatamodeld so that's why the error was being thrown. The definition existed in my class, but did not exist in the NSManagedEntity definition.